# In WebAuthn, is it possible for two different authenticators to store the same credential ID?

Tags: webauthn

In WebAuthn, is it possible for two different authenticators to store the same credential ID?
For example, let's say I registered a credential on my computer and I registered another
credential on my phone. Is it possible for my computer to store a credential with the same ID as my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passkeys are typically stored in multiple authenticators (synced between them), so in this case, the same credential ID will exist in multiple authenticators.

From a passkey creation standpoint, the odds of two authenticators creating a new passkey with the same credential ID are very low, as Nick mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

While this is technically possible, it's not something that you'd probably see. Credential IDs can be generated in two different forms, [as per the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#credential-id)

1. They can 16 bytes that include at least 100 bits of entropy
2. The public key credential source, without its Credential ID or mutable items, encrypted so only its managing authenticator can decrypt it.

So if you have an authenticator application running on your computer and phone that is capable of generating the same authentication assertions and credential IDs, it is possible, but it's better to enroll multiple credentials rather than create multiple authenticators that share private key material.